# Implementing a function that returns a n x m matrix in counter-clockwise spiral order starting from at the bottom right entry of the matrix

Tags: python, matrix

So I'm trying to implement a function in python that returns all elements of a n x m matrix in counter-clockwise spiral order, starting at the bottom furthest-right entry of the matrix.

For example, let's say the input was:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6],
          [7,8,9]]
```

Then our output would be `[9, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 5]`

In another case, if the

```
matrix = [[1,2],
          [3,4],
          [5,6]]
```

Then our output would be `[6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5]`

And finally, if the `matrix = [3]`, we'd return `[3]`.

The function I'm implementing follows this header:

```
def spiralOrder(matrix: list[list[int]]) -> list[int]:
```

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Have you tried to solve it using a pen and paper? Try with a 5x6 matrix and notice the pattern of the row/col indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a [while-loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp):

```
def spiralOrder(self, matrix: list[list[int]]) -> list[int]:
    result = []
    left, right = 0, len(matrix[0]) - 1
    up, down = 0, len(matrix) - 1
    step = 0
    while left <= right and up <= down:
        match step % 4:
            case 0:
                for i in range(down, up - 1, -1):
                    result.append(matrix[i][right])
                right -= 1
            case 1:
                for i in range(right, left - 1, -1):
                    result.append(matrix[up][i])
                up += 1
            case 2:
                for i in range(up, down + 1):
                    result.append(matrix[i][left])
                left += 1
            case 3:
                for i in range(left, right + 1):
                    result.append(matrix[down][i])
                down -= 1
        step += 1
    return result
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
print(spiralOrder([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
[9, 6, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 5]
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
print(spiralOrder([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
[6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
print(spiralOrder([[3]])
[3]
```

***Note:** `[3]` is a not of the type `list[list[int]]` hence I am assuming it is a typo in your question.*